# JavaScript Prime Checker Function with Ternary Operator Syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

How can I refactor the following using the ternary operator syntax instead?

```
let divisor = 2;
let isPrime = (num) => {
        if (num % divisor === 0) return false;
        else divisor++;
        return true;
};

console.log(`prime is ${isPrime(83)}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) operator following `:` at `exp2`

```js
let divisor = 2;
let isPrime = num => 
  num % divisor === 0 ? false : (++divisor, true);

console.log(`prime is ${isPrime(83)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the number and convert it to a Boolean, because numbers that are not 0 will be converted to `true`

```
(num) => num % divisor ? // > 0 == true : 0 == false
    !!(++divisor) // increment and convert to boolean
    : 
    false
```

```js
let divisor = 2;
const isPrime = (num) => num % divisor ? !!(++divisor) : false;

console.log(`prime is ${isPrime(83)}`);
```